# What are the image dimensions required for socia media to share web pages on social media

Tags: google-plus, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

What are the image dimensions required for socia media(ex facebook, twitter, linkedin, google) to share web pages on social media(ex facebook, twitter, linkedin, google)

Comment: How is this an AEM question?

Comment: It's not restricted to Aem but we are using AEM platform for building the pages

Answer (score 0):

This Is from IQ Wave solutions. As Per our concerns below are the some standard sizes of various social media Image posting sizes. 
Facebook cover image 820*310 px
Facebook logo size 180*180 px
Instagram Back Ground Image size - 1536*768 px
Youtube Channel
Cover photo - 2560*1440 px
Instagram
Profile Image - 110*100 px
Twitter
Profile photo - 400*400 px
Cover photo - 1500*500 px

Pinterest
Profile - 165*165

Tumblr - profile image - 128*128 px

Google +
Profile Image - 250*250 px
Cover Image - 1080*608 px

Let me know if anything than this...